# Issue when deploying Yesod 1.4 to Heroku

Tags: haskell, heroku, yesod

im having a problem when deploying a new Yesod application to heroku. I am following the steps here;

https://github.com/yesodweb/yesod/wiki/Deploying-Yesod-Apps-to-Heroku

But since yesod 1.4 was released, I am getting the following issue show up in my logs (PaperTrail);

Dec 21 04:42:51 fxtest heroku/web.1:  Starting process with command `./dist/build/fxtest/fxtest production -p 37347` 
Dec 21 04:42:52 fxtest app/web.1:  loadAppSettings: Could not parse file as YAML: production 
Dec 21 04:42:52 fxtest app/web.1:  fxtest: InvalidYaml (Just (YamlException "Yaml file not found: production")) 
Dec 21 04:42:53 fxtest heroku/web.1:  Process exited with status 1 
Dec 21 04:42:53 fxtest heroku/web.1:  State changed from starting to crashed

This appears to say that I have a missing yaml file called "production". If I try to negate this error by adding a dummy yaml file, then I get a similar error telling me I am missing a file called "-p". This leads me to think that the issue is being caused by my Procfile, which only contains one line;

web: ./dist/build/fxtest/fxtest production -p $PORT

thanks in advance for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using the new scaffolding, it no longer requires the command line parameter. Try dropping production from the command, and probably leave of the-p $PORT as well.

Comment: Thanks, that worked! :) BTW - how/where should I have found that out?

Comment: There was a blog post and email to the mailing list about the scaffolding changes: https://www.fpcomplete.com/blog/2014/12/experimental-packages-stackage